# How to enable aspectj compile time weaving with Java 7 and maven

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I have a project which currently works with java 6 and compile time weaving.
We use the following pom to enable spring aspects and our own ones:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <aspectLibraries>
          <aspectLibrary>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
          </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>test-compile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I've tried various configuration but can't make it work with java 7.
If someone could share a working pom or leads it would be great.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After moving to version 1.7.0 of the aspectjtools it works fine. In addition you need to pass the compiler the version parameter as `-1.7` (using the `target` parameter caused problems). If someone needs more details leave a comment and I'll add more configuration specific information.
**You can take a working example from here: [Spring, AspectJ and Maven example](https://github.com/avner-levy/minimal_spring_hibernate_maven_setup)**
Here is the working plugin definition from the pom (compiler-version="1.7", aspectj.version="1.7.0")

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <source>${compiler.version}</source>
        <target>${compiler.version}</target>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <complianceLevel>${compiler.version}</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml? At 1.7 when i do a clean build I get: org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: malformed org.aspectj.weaver.Declare attribute (length:45)org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: Bad type signature. But if i call mvn compile a second time, it builds, but later enhancements give a "Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target". I'm still looking into that.

Comment: I just moved to the newly released aspectj 1.7.0 and java 1.7, and am also getting the error about "Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target". Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you specify the right aspectj and compiler versions? I use it daily and it works great. Which part of the pom do you need (I'll add the missing parts)?

Comment: Thanks. Your plugin configuration helps me a lot. In my case it is working for aspectj version 1.6.12 without any problem.