# Maven doesn't weave aspectj code

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm facing problems to build an aspect project in eclipse with maven. When I run maven through eclipse "Run As > Maven build" I obtain this message: <...>/Clazz.java:[5,32] error: cannot find symbol. So, it looks like aspectj is not weaving the code through maven.

I distilled the problem until have class and an aspect that defines an intertype attribute in the mentioned class, as follows:

```
public class Clazz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Clazz().string);
    }
}

public aspect Aspect {

    public String Clazz.string = "string";

}
```

The pom.xml looks like this:

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718245/how-to-enable-aspectj-compile-time-weaving-with-java-7-and-maven?rq=1 It's not exactly your problem, but it will go a long way towards helping you out.

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears to be that the `maven-compiler-plugin` doesn't know to get out of the way when you have an AspectJ compile and throws errors that kill the build before `ajc` gets a chance to pull in the ITDs. My solution has been to disable `maven-compiler-plugin` entirely and let `ajc` handle compiling the `.java` files:

```
<!-- disable compiler because compiler chokes on ITDs -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If I do that the build works. However the generated jar doesn't have any class.

Comment: @Bruno Do you still have the AspectJ `compile` goal in place, and did you do a full clean and recompile?

Comment: No, I misinterpreted your answer and replaced aspectj plugin defintion by yours. So, now the build is working.

However, when I execute the jar through "java -jar" with the generated jar I'm obtaining a ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException. So, It looks like the compiled code have dependencies with aspectj lib, what is strange since my intention is to weave aspect code in compile time. Do you hagve any guess about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Bruno I'm not familiar enough with AspectJ to be able to tell, but that suggests that it's expecting the AspectJ RT. That's been my experience even with CTW (from Roo).

Comment: I already put "aspectjrt.jar" as dependency, as well as "aspectjtools.jar" in the following command: java -cp ".\lib\*" -jar perf-pocs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar (both jars are inside the lib folder) and the problem still persists. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, now is working. Just updating... I put the dependency inside the MANIFEST.MF of my jar like this "Class-Path: lib/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar".

Comment: @Bruno You should be using Maven to launch your program or build a "fat jar"; this applies to classpath dependencies generally.

Comment: @chrylis the time you just saved me!

Answer (score 5):

Actually you do not need to deactivate the Maven Compiler Plugin, but you need to do two things according to what I found out for someone who had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211943/aspectj-maven-plugin-declare-soft-how-to-compile/24341085#24341085):

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.1</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<!-- (...) -->

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <!-- IMPORTANT -->
        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- IMPORTANT -->
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I.e. you need to

- use incremental compilation in Maven Compiler Plugin 3.1 (attention, the switch is reversed, which is probably a bug) and
- assign execution phase "process-sources" to AspectJ Maven Plugin 1.6.

That should do it.