# Support for autowiring in a class not instantiated by spring (3)

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I realize this should be really basic but I haven't found a second step example after Helloworld

So what I have is:

spring config xml called spring-beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org" />

</beans>
```

A spring context initialized class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initialize Spring
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring-beans.xml");

    App app = (App) context.getBean("app");
    app.run();
}
```

Relevant details of AppImpl class:

```
@Component("app")
public final class AppImpl implements App{    

    // focus of question: This autowiring works
    @Autowired
    private DAO1 dao1;


    public void run() {
        //focus of question: This works as daoclass is instantiated properly                   
        obj1s = dao1.myFind();            

        badJobs = runJobs(obj1s);
    }

    private List<Obj1> runJobs(final List<Obj1> obj1s) {        
        List<Obj1> jobsGoneBad = new ArrayList<Obj1>();
        for (Obj1 next : obj1s) {

            // focus of question: usage of new keyword, thus not spring container managed?
            Job job = new JobImpl(next);
            job.run();

        }
        return jobsGoneBad;
    }    
}
```

Relevant details of JobImpl:

```
public class JobImpl implements Job {

    private Obj1 obj1;

    // focus of question: can't autowire
    @Autowired
    private DAO2 dao2;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //focus of question: opDAO == null - not initialized by @Autowired
        Obj2 obj2 = dao2.myFind();        
    }

}
```

Relevant details of DAO1:

```
@Repository("DAO1") //Focus of question: DAO1 is a repository stereotype
public class DAO1 {

    myfind() { ...}
}
```

Relevant details of DAO2:

```
@Repository("DAO2") //Focus of question: DAO2 is a repository stereotype
public class DAO2 {        

    myfind() { ...}
}
```

Right, so I initialize the App through a springcontext call and then succesfully instantiate a DAO1 instance through the use of @Autowired.

Then I create an unmanaged instance of Job and want to inject "singeltonish" dependencies in that class too by using @Autowired

Both Dao classes are spring stereotypes and scanner finds them fine.

So my question is basically, how should I instantiate the job instance so that I can use @Autowired concept inside it?

If I need a globally accessible applicationcontext, how do I best introduce that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring beans are singletons by default. However, what you need there are multiple instances, and on top of that, multiple instances created runtime.

One possibility is to use [method injection](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-method-injection) for this. You'd create a container aware job factory that would request new instances from the container.

(I think it is a bit fishy that you'd need a DAO reference injected in those runtime instances... I would maybe try rethinking the logic. Why couldn't you just provide the DAO reference in a constructor argument, for example, or use it from somewhere else altogether. You could have a method in the dao that would accept a Jobs instance, or a runWith(DAO2 dao) stuff in the JobImpl that would be satisfied with a class injected elsewhere, or a JobProcessor service that would have the daos injected and would ask the relevant info from Jobs instance...)

Comment: Thank you for being polite. :) would you mind elaborating on the "somewhere else altogether" thought.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Spring Bean functionality like injection only in spring managed beans!

But you can use the `@Configurable` Annotation, but this requires that you use REAL AspectJ.
If a class is annotated by `@Configurable` (and you use AspectJ) then you can use Springs Injection Annotations even if this class is created by a normal `new`.

@See

- Spring Reference: [Chapter 8.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)
- [Spring autowiring using @Configurable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703206/spring-autowiring-using-configurable)

Comment: This info is relevant to solve the problem with the current design, but I think the problem is better solved with a re-design as suggested in another post. Still clearly worth an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

@Autowired isn't working because your JobImpl object isn't managed by spring so it never has a chance to inject it. Spring managed beans are those where instances are created during component scan or in XML definition. JobImpl in your case is being instantiated as a normal Java object.

One solution would be to replace the auto-wiring with a manual lookup in the spring context.

```
private DAO2 dao2 = SpringApplicationContext.getApplicationContext ().getBean (DAO2.class);
```

@Autowired is working in @AppImpl because it's annotated as @Component. This flags it up for spring during its classpath scan where it will create an instance of this class and perform any autowiring/injections.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I knew why it wasn't working. I was more looking for input on the best alternative implementation to make it work. I don't think running to the application context each time I would need to solves it as good as the proposed redesign of another answer

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Component` annotation to your `JobImpl` class. Add component scan for this class in xml and your autowiring will work for `dao2`(provide getter-setter methods).

Comment: I don't think that's the problem - the problem is that he's creating the JobImpl class manually runtime, bypassing the spring container.

Comment: I get that, but as you might have noticed the JobImpl receives an Obj1 constructor argument and is meant to process several thousands of them which voids the option of using @Component as it is not an object with singelton behavior.