# Ehcache and spring bootstrapcacheloader not working

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache, terracotta

I am trying to setup a bootstrapcacheloader which will query the database and populate the cache. Here I am using ehcache integrated with spring. But the problem is that I am not able to get the dependencies wired into my cacheloader implementation. The @Autowired,@Resource,@Configurable none of them seem to work. Quite obviously the cacheloader instantiation is not done by Spring container , but is there a way I can inject a spring created cacheloader instance into the cachemanager and bootstrap it?
My implementation details below.
**ehcache.xml**

```
<cache name="MyCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="100000"
       eternal="false" 
       overflowToDisk="false"
       timeToLiveSeconds="500">
      <!--  <pinning store="localMemory"/> -->
      <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.tristargroup.claims.helper.ClaimsCacheLoaderFactory" properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true"/>
       <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.tristargroup.claims.helper.TristarCacheEventListenerFactory" listenFor="all"/>

</cache>
```

**Spring Context xml**

```
<cache:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager"><ref local="ehcache"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="cacheLoader">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

**Cache loader class**

```
 @Configurable
```

public class ClaimsCacheLoaderFactory extends BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory{

```
@Resource
CacheManager cacheManager;
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
public BootstrapCacheLoader createBootstrapCacheLoader(Properties arg0) {
    System.out.println("Create cache loader method . Cache manager is ->"+cacheManager);
    BootstrapCacheLoader cacheLoader = new ClaimsCacheLoader();
    return cacheLoader;
}
```

The cacheManager instance is always null here even if I specify it as an Autowired attribute.
The problem is present even in the cache event listeners. 
Someone please help me on this.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703206/spring-autowiring-using-configurable

Answer (score 0):

If the cacheManager is null, Tthat means you haven't made the bean available to your package. Add a @ComponentScan("yourpackage") in the same place you defined your bean and add @Component where you want to use your cacheManager.
This is old, but i hope it helps someone else.