# Spring context with jUnit for @Configurable code: NullPointerException for Resource

Tags: java, spring, junit, nullpointerexception, junit4

I have a production class which looks like

```
@Configurable
public class MyProductionClass {
  @Resource private MyResource resource;
  private String param;    

  public MyProductionClass(String param) {
    this.param = param
  }

  public void aMethod() {
    resource.doSomething();
    //whatever, the previous line throws NullPointerException when testing
  }
}
```

and a test class like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test-context.xml"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class MyProductionClassTest {

  private MyProductionClass underTest;

  @Test
  public void aMethodTest() {
    underTest = new MyProductionClass("aString");
    underTest.aMethod();
  }
}
```

I have some log and I can see Spring context being initialized correctly, with all beans described in `test-context.xml` happily created, including `resource`.

But, when the test runs `underTest.aMethod()` a `NullPointerException` is thrown saying `resource is null`.

I use the same initialization (`new MyProductionClass("aString")`) in production and there everything works flawlessly. Is there something I am missing when using `@Configurable` classes with `jUnit`?

Versions are:

- Spring `3.2.4`
- jUnit `4.11`

**EDIT** My understanding of `@Configurable`: this issue may come from a misunderstanding of this feature. I understood it works so that I am not force to statically declare my `@Configurable` class in any Spring context (either Java or XML based), but so that I can initialized the class with the `new` operator and *magically* dependency are injected in the class. However, I do not know if this can work for tests (and I do not find any reason why it should not, a `new` is a `new`, whether it comes from a test class or from a production one)

Answer (score 0):

you must get the bean from spring container

```
@Autowired
private MyProductionClass underTest;
...
@Test
public void aMethodTest() {
underTest.aMethod();
}
```

Comment: You're right that the class under test _must_ come from the Spring container (strictly, from the context), but I'm not sure how that works with JUnit…

Comment: I am using `@Configurable`, so I think I do not need `MyProductionClass` to be declared in the Spring context and thus `Autowired`. See my edit to check my understanding of this Spring feature.

Comment: check your test-context.xml,[spring-autowiring-using-configurable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703206/spring-autowiring-using-configurable),**@Configurable** use **AspectJ compiler**,i think load-time weaving  is not enable in your test context