# Spring: @Autowired for POJO, that not managed by Spring

Tags: spring

i use the @Autowired to inject some services in the POJOs. The servieces are registred as Beans.

If once POJO is managed by Spring (it is registred as Bean on Spring Config too), so i have no problem with injected services.

But if i created "classic" POJO and create it by "new" , so no Services will be injected.

My question: is it possible to configurate Spring, to realize the @Autowired injection?

I use the Spring 4.0.3 that is configured by JavaConfig:

====

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ConsumerTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView;

import com.tr.oauth.service.PhotoInfo;
import com.tr.oauth.service.PhotoService;
import com.tr.oauth.service.impl.PhotoServiceImpl;
import com.tr.oauth.service.oauth.ExtendedApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

   @Bean
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver() throws Exception {
        ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
        contentNegotiationManager.addMediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        MappingJackson2JsonView defaultView = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
        defaultView.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);

        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        contentViewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(contentNegotiationManager.getObject());
        contentViewResolver.setViewResolvers(Arrays.<ViewResolver>asList(viewResolver));
        contentViewResolver.setDefaultViews(Arrays.<View>asList(defaultView));
        return contentViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @Bean
    public PhotoServiceUserController photoServiceUserController(PhotoService photoService) {
       PhotoServiceUserController photoServiceUserController = new PhotoServiceUserController();
       return photoServiceUserController;
    }

    @Bean
    public PhotoController photoController(PhotoService photoService) {
        PhotoController photoController = new PhotoController();
        photoController.setPhotoService(photoService);
        return photoController;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessConfirmationController accessConfirmationController(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService, ApprovalStore approvalStore) {
        AccessConfirmationController accessConfirmationController = new AccessConfirmationController();
        accessConfirmationController.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        accessConfirmationController.setApprovalStore(approvalStore);
        return accessConfirmationController;
    }

    @Bean
    public PhotoServiceImpl photoServices() {
        List<PhotoInfo> photos = new ArrayList<PhotoInfo>();
        photos.add(createPhoto("1", "marissa"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("2", "paul"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("3", "marissa"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("4", "paul"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("5", "marissa"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("6", "paul"));

        PhotoServiceImpl photoServices = new PhotoServiceImpl();
        photoServices.setPhotos(photos);
        return photoServices;
    }


    @Bean
    public AdminController adminController(TokenStore tokenStore, ConsumerTokenServices tokenServices,
            ExtendedApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler) {
        AdminController adminController = new AdminController();
        adminController.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        adminController.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        adminController.setUserApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler);
        return adminController;
    }

   private PhotoInfo createPhoto(String id, String userId) {
        PhotoInfo photo = new PhotoInfo();
        photo.setId(id);
        photo.setName("photo" + id + ".jpg");
        photo.setUserId(userId);
        photo.setResourceURL("/impl/resources/" + photo.getName());
        return photo;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}


-----------

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer;

/**
 * @author Dave Syer
 * 
 */
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.scan(ClassUtils.getPackageName(getClass()));
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        DelegatingFilterProxy filter = new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain");
        filter.setContextAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher");
        servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", filter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes this is possible with the `@Configurable` annotation and some byte-code magic.

Oliver Gierke the guy behind `Spring Data` created a nice blog post on this topic:
http://olivergierke.de/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/
http://aredko.blogspot.de/2011/02/using-configurable-in-spring-framework.html

There is also a question with no accepted answer on SO:
[Spring autowiring using @Configurable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703206/spring-autowiring-using-configurable)