# How can I inject a date provider into a JPA Entity class?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My JPA Entity classes have a @PrePersist method to set an INSERT_TIME column:

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    insertTime = new Date(); // TODO: inject time source?
}
```

For testing, I would like to replace `new Date()` so that entities are persisted with predictable data.  My first thought was to have a data provider injected into the Entity class, but I don't control the creation of Entity classes, so it doesn't seem there is a way for me to inject dependencies.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not move this logic into your dao/service layer where you have injection available? Pojos are generally best kept as dumb as possible

Comment: @radai At least in a Spring environment injection into pojo is simple see `@Configurable`. Imho advising people to keep the domain layer dumb is not a good advise: http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839484/spring-autowired-for-pojo-that-not-managed-by-spring/