# Spring: Dependency injection info

Tags: spring

Can I use the Dependency Injection in this case ?
How can I configure the bean Article in the applicationContext.xml?

```
public class Test{

public void methodX(){
   .....
    while{

     Article a=new Article();
     ...
    }//while 
}//methodX
}//Test
```

Edit:

This is the solution which I have used:

```
 package factory;

 import bean.ArticoliOrdine;

 public abstract class ArticlesFactory {
   public abstract Article createArticle();
 }

 @Transational
 public class CartDAOImpl implements CartDAO {
    @Autowired
     private Cart cart;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    ArticlesFactory articlesFactory;

    public void buy(){  
          ....
     while{
        Article article=articlesFactory.createArticle();
              .....
        em.persist(article);
     }//while
    }//buy
 }//CartDAOImpl
```

In applicationContext

```
    <bean id="articolesFactory" class="factory.ArticlesFactory">
       <lookup-method name="createArticles" bean="articles"/>
    </bean>

   <bean class="bean.Articles" id="articles" scope="prototype"/>
```

Comment: Make `Article` `@Configurable`. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4703206/1686330

Comment: I used Lookup method injection.Is it a good solution?

Comment: I'm afraid i didn't got your question right. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I created outside the method `@Autowired ArticleFactory articleF;`, using Lookup method injection, and I obtain a new instance of bean Article , calling `articlef.getInstance()` [link :)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch03s04.html#beans-factory-method-injection)

Comment: That's a bit over engineered. See my answer.

Comment: @DirkLachowski Why did you delete your comments? With your example Configurable I had learned a new thing

Comment: Oops, i thought you didn't liked it. Undeleting...

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to achieve that:

1. Make `Article` `@Configurable`: 
   @Configurable is a spring feature that allows you to configure (hence the name) instances that are not created under container control - as your `Article` instance named `a`.

To make a class `@Configurable` you simply annotate it. After that, you can inject dependencies into that class as if it was created by the container. 
Example:

```
@Configurable
public class Article {
    // This gets injected every time you instantiate a new Article by 'new Article()'
    @Autowired private SomeOtherClass dependency;
}
```

The downside: This uses aspects to do its magic, so you will have to either use compile time weaving or load time weaving (preferred). If you want to give it a try: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw

2. Create a factory and inject it into class `Test`:

   ```
   @Component
   public class ArticleFactory {
       // Any stuff you want to configure article with
       @Autowired private SomeOtherClass dependency;

       public Article get() {
           Article a = new Article();
           a.setStuff(dependency);
           return a;
       }
   }
   ```

and later in class `Test`:

```
@Component
public class Test{

    @Autowired private ArticleFactory factory;

    public void methodX(){
       .....
        while{

           Article a = factory.get();
           ...
        }//while 
    }//methodX
}//Test
```

Comment: As you are not showing your code it's hard to tell. Add your solution as an answer.

Comment: The solution is described in this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch03s04.html#beans-factory-method-injection)

Comment: I know lookup method injection, but without knowing your code using it (i suppose your code is doing more than the `Test` class you posted) it's hard to decide. If i had to make a guess i would say that that's not the way you want to go, especially because your `Article` class is not managed. Using method lookup you are depending on CGLIB and then it's no big step to a `@Configurable`. If you want the simplest solution  (in terms of libs depending on and avoiding trouble) you should use my second suggestion.

Comment: But in your second suggestion , Article is not managed by Spring Container.Later I will insert the solution

Comment: That's correct, that is what you have asked for in your question: How to configure an object not created by the container.

Comment: Sorry but my bad English didn't understand the question to you.I wanted to know how to initialize/create Article in Spring container.Sorry again..for that your solution was strange..

Comment: Is it a good solution if I use a `Provider<Article>` or a `ObjectFactory<Article>` instead of using lookup method injection?