# Autowire in An Nonbean Class using AspectJ

Tags: java, spring

AppConfig contains Java Configuration.

```
package com.wh;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableLoadTimeWeaving;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.EnableSpringConfigured;

@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public EchoService echoService(){

          return new EchoService();
    }
@Bean
    public InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver()  throws Throwable {
    InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver = new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
    return loadTimeWeaver;
    }
}
```

Service Class

```
package com.wh;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EchoService {
    public void echo( String s ) {
        System.out.println( s );
    }
}
```

EchoDelegateService is the Non Bean class in which we have Autowired The required Bean.
We expect that the EchoService should get autowired.

Problem : EchoService not getting autowired. Gives an Null Pointer exception.

```
package com.wh;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

@Configurable( preConstruction = true, autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE, dependencyCheck = false )
public class EchoDelegateService {
    @Autowired
    private EchoService echoService;

    public void echo( String s ) {
        echoService.echo( s );
    }
}
```

Main Class where we are calling method of NonBean Class.

```
package com.wh;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          ApplicationContext ctx = 
          new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

          new EchoDelegateService().echo("hihi, it works...");
       }
}
```

Comment: worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703206/spring-autowiring-using-configurable Do you have some kind of weaving enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Your question already includes the answer: "... in a non-bean class". This simply does not work. All the autowiring, aspect resolving and whatever is to that, **only** works for beans. Thus, you definitely need to construct your EchoDelegateService via the spring factory:

```
EchoDelegateService myService = ctx.getBean(EchoDelegateService.class);
myService.echo("this should really work now");
```