# Injecting Spring Data Repository into arbitrary classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository, spring-data

I have created a few interfaces extending `CrudRepository`. I'd like to use them into a generic class that is not a bean. What I do currently is to inject them using `@Autowired` inside my `RestController` and then pass them down as method arguments to this generic class I'm talking about. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring autowiring using @Configurable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703206/spring-autowiring-using-configurable)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to make your unmanaged class extending [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html) and use @Autowired properties. If your application has a Spring web application context, it can then try to get the context from the current thread and resolve the @Autowired properties for you.