# Spring - Autowire Service into POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a model in which I want to inject my service.

**My Model**

```
@Configurable
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public Class User {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

{
   System.out.println("Trying Service : " + userService.getMyName()); 
}

}
```

Here I get always a `NullPointerException` on 7'th line.

In my spring-context.xml I have :

```
<context:spring-configured/>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

**EDIT**

**UserService**

```
@Component
public Class UserService {

  public String getMyName() { return "it's Me!";}

}
```

Comment: Please provide code of `UserService` and your spring context XML file, provided information is not sufficient to say anything deterministically.

Comment: Ok check now, i've edited it

Comment: This is not good approach to inject bean into data model. Why do you need this injection?

Comment: You need to have component scan and annotation driven entries in your spring XML file, something like this `<context:component-scan base-package="com.cgi.itd"/>
 <mvc:annotation-driven />` and I don't know about `@Configurable` whether it is spring annotation to make the class as bean or not, if not then you have to use `@Component` or similar spring annotation

Comment: **UserService** is just a class that I use like a middle man between my classes and a **.properties** file.

Comment: @hagrawal I already have that in my context and I tried `@Component` still no luck

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703781/4920138

Comment: Just check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879092/5790398. I think you need AspectJ dependency and configure weaving properly. Then it should works.

Comment: How are you getting a `User` instance? Because if you're just making `new User()` Spring won't be able to inject any dependency

Comment: Ok, then how you are creating object of your `User` class?

Comment: @Pelocho actually `user` is an `entity` so I get the error while the application is starting

Comment: As far as I know Spring doesn't initialize any `Entity` at init time. Try debugging the exception to see if it's Spring indeed who is raising the exception or it comes from your code

Comment: You cannot do that. The initializer block is part of the constructor, dependencies are injected AFTER the object has been constructed. You are trying to use it before it ever could be injected.

Comment: Yeah now I know, actually i puted that line just for testing, but even when i removed it the problem still persists and the service always null

Answer (score 5):

Spring managed components can be wired only into another beans managed by Spring.

However, there is a trick to add service to your POJO if you really need it:

1. Add UserService as a static field to your POJO with a setter
2. In UserService after spring initializes the bean, set itself as a field on the POJO (this can be done in @PostConstruct method)

Comment: Can you write the code because what you said is unclear to me

Answer (score 1):

Make a static instance of UserService available:

```
@Service
public Class UserService {
    private static UserService instance;
    public static UserService getInstance() { return instance; }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() { instance = this; }

    public String getMyName() { return "it's Me!";}
}
```

call with:

```
UserService.getInstance().getMyName()
```